# QGIS does not load Luxembourg TIF/TFW file

Tags: qgis, raster, import, world-file, luxembourg

I am trying to load the topographical map from Luxembourg into QGIS.

The .tif and .tfw were downloaded from the [lu cadastre](https://data.public.lu/en/datasets/carte-topographique-numerique-a-lechelle-1-50000/). But when importing into QGIS it does not recognize a correct projection.

I tried to convert the file and told it to use a projection. But that is not working.

How can I import the imagery into QGIS with a correct projection?

Comment: You must know the correct projection yourself. The tiff file itself is an ungeoreferenced image and the .TFW file does not tell the coordinate reference system. Probably the download site has metadata about the dataset somewhere, but if not, ask from the data provider.

Comment: What exactly did you download, and can you post it with a link to DropBox, etc?

Comment: I downloaded the '50k-2019-lux.zip' file from the given link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TIFF doesn't have a projection set. If you set the projection to [EPSG:2169](https://epsg.io/2169) (LUREF / Luxembourg TM) it will display correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it. 
I could not find the correct projection within the metadata on the cadastre website. But somehow it is obvious that it should be a Luxembourg projection.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the few times that you can use the set projection in QGis. You'll need to find out what projection is correct for your imagery and set that. Then you should export the data into a Geotiff which will store the projection with the data for you.

Comment: Exporting it into a GeoTIFF is a good suggestion. Finding out the correct projection was cruel, especially with a language barrier.